# Cannot reset input fields after submitting form in React

Tags: reactjs, api, axios

I have a form with input fields. After submitting form input fields need to be cleared. I tried to set state to empty array - it didn'd work, then I tried to use refs - didn't work for me either...

This function activates onSubmit event.

```
addHaspInfo = (e) => {  
 // e.preventDefault();  
    axios.post("/hasp", {
      company: {
            name: e.target[3].value,
            city: e.target[4].value,
            phone: e.target[5].value
            },
            numberOfKeys: e.target[2].value,                      
            serial: e.target[0].value,
            soft: e.target[1].value,
      })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      })
      axios.get("/hasp") 
      .then((haspData) => {
        console.log(haspData.data);
        this.setState({
          hasps: haspData.data
        });
      }); 
      this.setState({
          hasps: []      //this don't reset input fields
        });        
  }
```

```
<form id="formId" className="form-group haspAddForm" onSubmit={this.addHaspInfo}>
```

Ant this didn't work too:

```
 clearInput = () => {
        this.setState({hasps: []});
        ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.myInput).focus();  //this don't reset input fields
       }
```

```
<button onClick={this.clearInput} className="btn btn-primary" type="submit"  style={{marginBottom:'40px', marginRight: '110px'}}>Add new hasp info</button>
```

One of the input fields

```
<input ref="myInput" type="text" className="form-control" value={this.state.serial} placeholder="00000-00000" required /><br />
```

Comment: do you expect that `this.setState({hasps: []});` will wipe out state and insert `hasps: []` only? because actually `.setState` patches state not replaces it

Comment: React is new for me, so I do not understand all nuances)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of your input is `this.state.serial`. To reset the input value, you can set 'serial' property on state to empty string.

Example:

```
this.setState({ serial: "" })
```

On your code, you are setting hasp property to empty array. But you are not using this property on your input field. So, reset this property has no effect. You need to reset on your state, all properties that you use on the `value` prop of the inputs on you form.

I suggest that you read https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html to understand how forms works on react.

On your submit function, you can get the values from the state. It's not necessary  use `e.target` array. This leaves the code confuse.

The best approach on react, is use controlled inputs. You can see: https://goshakkk.name/controlled-vs-uncontrolled-inputs-react/

Comment: when I add your code, input field "serial" clears, but I have error : Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa). ...

Comment: Yea, I definitely need to check documents))

Comment: You need to use controlled components. to do that, you need to add onChange function on your input, to update the state with the new value of serial.

Comment: It worked for me. I added in state every value equal "", then created onChange function for every value, and then after submiting form again use setState for every value equal "". One thing, now I have onChange function for every input. Is there a chance to do it more elegant, for example one func. onChange for every field?

Comment: now I have: onChangeSerial = (event) => {
    this.setState({serial: event.target.value});
  }

  onChangeSoft = (event) => {
    this.setState({soft: event.target.value});
  }   and 4 other functions

Comment: Yes, you can do:
onChangeInput = (key, value) => { this.setState({ [key]: value }); }

And on your input:
<input onChange={(event) => this.onChangeInput('serial', event.target.value)}/>

Comment: Or, one more advanced way, is use closure.
onChangeInput = (key) => event => { this.setState({ [key]: event.target.value }); }

And on your input: <input onChange={this.onChangeInput('serial')} />

Closures: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/javascript-closures-simplified-d0d23fa06ba4

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
clearInput = ()=>{
  this.setState({...this.state,
                  serial: ""
                })
  }
```

This is how you reset the input fields. Spread in the state, then set the state that represents the value of the input fields to empty strings.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work for me. When I add this code - I have an error(

Comment: if you send me the github repo i can debug it. this is just the concept of how it works i can't give you exact code without seeing all of it

Answer (score 0):

Try passing a callback to your `.setState()` method. That worked for me.

```
this.setState({
  hasps: []      
  }, e.target.reset()
);
```